# How to use beginless range in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

**Update: This issue has since been fixed in Rails 6.1**

I'm getting some inconsistent behavior in Rails 6.0.2.2 when passing beginless and endless ranges to `where`:

```
pry(main)> User.where(id: 1..3).ids
   (8.0ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" 
    WHERE "users"."id" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 LIMIT $3  [["id", 1], ["id", 3]]
=> [1, 2, 3]

pry(main)> User.where(id: 1..).ids
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" 
    WHERE "users"."id" >= $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1]]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

pry(main)> User.where(id: ..3).ids
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users"
    WHERE "users"."id" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 LIMIT $3 [["id", nil], ["id", 3]]
=> []
```

When using and endless range inside of `where`, the generated SQL uses `WHERE >=` the beginning of the range instead of `BETWEEN`.

However, when passing a beginless range, it generates a SQL where clause `BETWEEN NULL` and tne end of the range.

Is this an known issue in ActiveRecord?

---

Comment: Its not a nil minimum value. `..3` is a range from infinity to 3.

Comment: @max yes but this actually works if you do `Float::INFINITY..3`. You get `[1,2,3]` back. I've just realized that beginless ranges were only added in Ruby 2.7, and endless ranges were added in Ruby 2.6. So it looks like Rails just hasn't added this for Ruby 2.7 yet

Comment: Ah its pretty easy see why this happens when you do `Float::INFINITY..3.begin == Float::INFINITY.` and `..3.begin == nil`

Comment: This is actually fixed in 6.1 and the fix is scheduled to be backported to 6.0.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36696

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like an issue in ActiveRecord and you can get around it by using Arel or Float::INFINITY.

```
Client.where(Client.arel_table[:id].gte(id))
Client.where(id: Float::INFINITY..3)
```

The issue [is solved in Rails 6.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36696) and is due to be backported to 6.0.

Comment: I actually didn't know that you could use an infinite range to create GTE which is pretty cool. You might want to check the issues if this has been reported as a bug and submit an issue otherwise. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html